# Slack as a Gnome Web Web-Application keeps asking for permission to show desktop notifications

Tags: gnome, webapps, slack

I'm using Gnome Web (web browser) to run slack as a web application so that I can search for it as an app in the Ubuntu Gnome activities screen. This works well but everytime I start the Web App I get asked by if slack.com can set desktop notifications.

I also use web.skype.com as a web application too and was only ever asked once if skype.com could set desktop notifications.

Does anyone know what the problem might be or how I can fix it.

Comment: Sounds like the session information or cookies are not persisting between uses.  I'm curious why you don't just use the Slack desktop app for Ubuntu? I'm not a Gnome user, so I may be missing something, but wouldn't the native app show up in the Gnome activities screen?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I never knew about this app. It works fine.